# How to set minimum collision angle for SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicscontact

How can I set a minimum collision angle for an SKSpriteNode object so that when it collides with any other sprite, its reversed angle is always greater than or equal to this angle - either negative or positive - ?

My objective is to prevent deadlock collision between two parallel edges - for example -, so that the ball won't oscillate between them forever.

Comment: One temporary solution I have found is checking the sprite's velocity when it collides and if it is less than minimum value, apply impulse on the sprite with large values to avoid deadlock. I have also tried to set the dx and dy of the velocity, but this changed the sprite speed significanlty, which I didn't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have found a solution - may be not the best but it works fine -.

When the sprite collides with other one, I find the sprite velocity angle from the equation: 


angle = atan(dy/dx) 


and check the angle value. If it is less than the min one, I set the angle to the min value and then find the new velocity dy from the equation:


dy_new = dx * tan(new_angle)


and find the dx_new from the equation:


dx_new = sqrt(pow(dx, 2) + pow(dy, 2) - pow(dx_new, 2));


This means that the speed magnitude is the same but only the direction is changed.
This is based on the vectors equations:


speed = sqrt(pow(dx, 2) + pow(dy, 2));   and 

angle = atan(dy/dx);

Here is the link of the velocity vectors mathematics:
http://faculty.wwu.edu/vawter/PhysicsNet/Topics/Vectors/TheVelocityVector.html